# Why won't this line of code execute when there are no syntax error, or runetime errors

Tags: java

When I run the code I do not get my desired result for the **setDepartment method**. I'm trying to trap the user if they entered a wrong selection. When I execute the code and put in a value (string) that should without a doubt execute, it does not execute. I have tested to see where the problem could lay. The only thing that worked is when I tried hardcoding the correct value into the method. If I put in an incorrect value and trap the user, and put in the correct value, the user is still trapped in the loop. I checked to see if there are any logical errors in my loop, but I could not find a problem. I am at a complete loss, I can't wait to find what I messed up on.

Please ignore the **courseCost instance variable** I haven't worked on that yet, and please disregard the **system.out.println(department)** after the **department = department.toUpperCase** in the **setDepartment method**. I was using the **system.out.println(department)** in the **setDepartment method** to rule out any possible errors that may have been on the **department = department.toUpperCase** line of code. Also, you can ignore everything else, everything else works just fine. Thank you for taking the time to take a look.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Course {
    static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String department;
    private int courseNumber;
    private int courseCredits;
    private double courseCost;

    public Course () {
        department = "unknown";
        courseNumber = 0;
        courseCost = 0;
        courseCredits = 0;
    }

    public Course(String department, int courseNumber, int courseCredits) {
        setDepartment(department);
        setCourseNumber(courseNumber);
        setCourseCredits(courseCredits);
        //courseCost = no value will be passed to the constructor, courseCost will be calculated as courseCredits/2 * $500, see setter below (if the course is a Lab Course add $100 to the cost)
    }

    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public int getCourseNumber() {
        return courseNumber;
    }

    public int getCourseCredits() {
        return courseCredits;
    }

    public double getCourseCost() {
        return courseCost;
    }

    public void setDepartment(String department) {

        boolean enteredCorrectly = false;
        //department = department.toUpperCase();

        do{
            department = department.toUpperCase();
            System.out.println(department);
            //ENGL, MATH, COMP, HIST, HUMN, SCIE, LANG, PHYS
            if( (department == "ENGL") || (department == "MATH") || (department == "COMP") || 
                (department == "HIST") || (department == "HUMN") || (department == "SCIE") || 
                (department == "LANG") || (department == "PHYS") ) {
                this.department = department;
                enteredCorrectly = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please re-enter a valid department.");
                department = keyboard.nextLine();

            }
        } while(!(enteredCorrectly));

    }

    public void setCourseNumber(int courseNumber) {

        boolean enterCorrectly = false;

        do{
            if(1 <= courseNumber && courseNumber <= 399) {
                this.courseNumber = courseNumber;
                enterCorrectly = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please re-enter a valid course number.");
                courseNumber = keyboard.nextInt();
                keyboard.nextLine();
            }
        } while(!(enterCorrectly));

    }

    public void setCourseCredits(int courseCredits) {

        boolean enterCorrectly = false;

        do{
            if(courseCredits == 3 || courseCredits == 4 || courseCredits == 6) {
                this.courseCredits = courseCredits;
                enterCorrectly = true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Please re-enter a valid course credits.");
                courseCredits = keyboard.nextInt();
                keyboard.nextLine();
            }
        } while(!(enterCorrectly));

    }

    public void setCourseCost(double courseCost) {
        this.courseCost = courseCost;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Course c = new Course ("engl", 991, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Please ignore [...]" hello and welcome. Please remove irrelevant code from the question.

Comment: You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Finally, how did you establish that the method is not being run? Are you sure the client code that's using this class is not catching and ignoring exceptions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @Federico, yes it does, thank you very very much! Also, I will make sure to remove irrelevant code, thank you for the feedback on both my problems!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason it is not giving you the expected results is because in the comparison block you are using the operator `==`, which means you are comparing the reference of the strings:

```
if( (department == "ENGL") || (department == "MATH") || (department == "COMP") || 
    (department == "HIST") || (department == "HUMN") || (department == "SCIE") || 
    (department == "LANG") || (department == "PHYS") ) {
    this.department = department;
    enteredCorrectly = true;
}
```

In Java, to compare the value of strings, you should use the [`.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method:

```
if( (department.equals("ENGL") || (department.equals("MATH") || (department.equals("COMP") || 
    (department.equals("HIST") || (department.equals("HUMN") || (department.equals("SCIE") || 
    (department.equals("LANG") || (department.equals("PHYS") ) {
    this.department = department;
    enteredCorrectly = true;
}
```

Comment: If that's the case then the question is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) and should be marked as such, not answered.

Comment: How would a beginner have known to look for a question on string equality?

Comment: I should kiss both of you Federico & @Thiago.. *muah* *muah* (no homo) Man, you guys don't know how long I've been stuck on this, thank you very much!

Comment: You too @NomadMaker, thank you! I agree with you, perhaps they could create a bot that allows questions to remain up until the noob (me) sees it and then they can take it down. I think that would be an awesome feature.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Sorry about that. I am getting familiar with answering questions. Could you please tell me how I should proceed?

Comment: @ThiagoNobayashi don't worry, I was not reprimanding you, just using this as a teaching opportunity :)

Comment: @NomadMaker nothing in particular, I was just pointing out that there's another answer answering the same basic question. It's not like I'm bashing Thiago or OP :)

Answer (score 0):

the probable reason is in two thing - declaring a private global variable:

```
private String department;
```

and these lines:

```
department = department.toUpperCase();
System.out.println(department);
```

To my mind, the problem is in same names between global private var and method param.
Just try to rename the method parameter to **departmentParam** (for example) and then try to print it.

Comment: I'm not so sure. Later on they do `this.department = department` so apparently they know what they're doing in that fragment. The only despicable thing is the choice of the name, but otherwise it should work as intended.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Villa, it's very much appreciated. This wasn't the problem, however, the problem was we can't use "==" to compare strings, the preferred way is .equals method!